# Play framework reading cookie from Javascript, is it safe?

Tags: java, scala, security, cookies, playframework

Im looking at https://github.com/jamesward/play-rest-security.

So what it does, is that after User is authenticated successfully, a cookie will be generated. Then, the javascript side will check if this Cookie(only possible without httpOnly) exist by reading `document.cookie`. After that client side will read the token and assign it to `window.token`. This token is used to validate request for AJAX calls(appended to the header when making AJAX calls).

So, my question is that, is it possible for just a normal user. To read this cookie via `document.cookie` on console and then use it to make AJAX calls to the server?

Is it safe to implement this in a non single page application ?

Comment: I'm not sure what is your concern here? Of course, users can access their own cookies - but they got those cookies after properly authenticating on your website anyway, so they would just be spoofing _their own identity_.